# Django MultipleChoiceField choices of users throws error

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I am trying to write a form that allows the user to select as many users from a specific group as they want. However when I try to use the list of users as an option I get an error saying that 'User' object does not support indexing.

Its a fairly standard form, the main difference is that the group is filtered based on a kwarg passed to the form. The form is passed a project_id (project object primary key) and it then finds the group associated with that project and generates the field.

From forms.py

```
class ModifyTeamForm(forms.Form):

    action = ChoiceField(choices=[('remove', 'Remove users'), ('promote', 'Promote to lead.')])



    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        # The project to get the team for
        project_id = kwargs.pop('project_id', None)

        super(ModifyTeamForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        project = Project.objects.get(pk=project_id)

        # Team for this project
        team = User.objects.filter(groups__name=project.project_name)

        # Create a form field to select current team members
        current_team = MultipleChoiceField(required=True, choices = team, widget=CheckboxSelectMultiple)

        # Add the field
        self.fields['current_team'] = current_team
```

My views.py

```
@login_required
def team(request, project_id): 

    if request.method == "POST": 
        # Not yet implemented
        return
    else: 
        form = ModifyTeamForm(project_id=project_id)

        template = loader.get_template('projects/team.html')

        context = RequestContext(request, {
            'form': form,
        })

        return HttpResponse(template.render(context))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because `MultipleChoiceField.choices` is expected to be a 2d Array effectively (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ChoiceField.choices).

So you could do something like this:

```
team = [(u.pk, u.email) for u in User.objects.filter(groups__name=project.project_name)]
```

And that will return you a list continaing the combintation of

```
[('user1.pk', 'user1.email'), ('user2.pk', 'user2.email'),...]
```

which will be useable as the `choices`.